# appending json files to text file

Tags: python, json

I have a list, where each element is path to json file. i am using following code to write into a text file:

```
list=['C:/Users/JAYANTH/Desktop/datasets/580317556516483072/source-
tweet/580317556516483072.json', 
'C:/Users/JAYANTH/Desktop/datasets/580317998147325952/source-
tweet/580317998147325952.json', 
..........]
file=open("abc.txt","a")
for i in range(len(list))
    with open(list[i]) as f:
        u=json.load(f)
        s=json.dumps(u)
        file.write(s)
file.close()
```

this code appends data in json files to txt file. While trying to read the data from same file using following code:

```
with open('abc.txt','r') as f:
    for each in f:
        print(json.load(file))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JAYANTH\Desktop\proj\apr25.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(json.load(file))
  File "C:\Users\JAYANTH\Desktop\proj\lib\json\__init__.py", line 268, in 
   load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, 
  **kw)
  File "C:\Users\JAYANTH\Desktop\proj\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in 
  loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\JAYANTH\Desktop\proj\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in 
  decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\JAYANTH\Desktop\proj\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in 
  raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have also tried using json.loads, but getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JAYANTH\Desktop\proj\apr25.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(json.loads(file))
  File "C:\Users\JAYANTH\Desktop\proj\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in 
  loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: When you read "abc.txt", why do you have a for loop. Just have print(json.load(f))

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could just create one outer list, append each of your individual json objects to this outler list, which itself becomes a single, valid, json object. Then just write that to a file.

Answer (score 0):

A concatenation of json is not json, full stop. This file is a valid Json:

```
[ 1, 2 ,
  { "a": "b" },
  3 ]
```

and give this Python object: `[1, 2, {'a': 'b'}, 3]`

But this is no longer a valid json file:

```
[ 1, 2 ,
  { "a": "b" },
  3 ]
[ 1, 2 ,
  { "a": "b" },
  3 ]
```

because it contains 2 object with no relations.

You should enclose everything in an outer list to make it valid:

```
[
[ 1, 2 ,
  { "a": "b" },
  3 ]
,
[ 1, 2 ,
  { "a": "b" },
  3 ]
]
```

So you generating code should be:

```
file=open("abc.txt","a")
file.write("[\n")            # start of a list
first = True
for i in range(len(list))
    if first: 
        first = False
    else: 
        file.write(",\n")    # add a separating comma before every element but the first one
    with open(list[i]) as f:
        u=json.load(f)
        s=json.dumps(u)
        file.write(s)
file.write("]\n")            # terminate the list
```

file.close()